# How to move files to archive and error folders after processing

Tags: spring-batch

Job runs once and try to process all the files available in a source folder in a step. Further it need to do removal of processed/tried but failed files from the source folder to another subsequent folders (/_archived, /_faild). What is the best way to move successfully processed files in archive folder and unsuccessfull files in error folder categorically using spring batch.

Comment: I second the answer by @Niraj Sonawane. This is how I would do it too.

Answer (score 4):

you can add separate `tasklet` or use `JobExecutionListener.afterJob` hook to move files.

Below is sample example for moving files using `tasklet`

Java config

```
@autowired
private MoveFilesTasklet moveFilesTasklet


    @Bean
    protected Step moveFiles() {
        return steps
          .get("moveFiles")
          .tasklet(moveFilesTasklet)
          .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public Job job() {
        return jobs
          .get("taskletsJob")
          .start(processFiles())
          .next(moveFiles())          
          .build();
```

**Tasklet**

```
@Component
public class MoveFilesTasklet implements Tasklet {     
        private String filePath ="someFilePAth";

    @Override
    public RepeatStatus execute(StepContribution stepContribution, ChunkContext chunkContext) throws Exception {    

        final File directory = new File(filePath);
        Arrays.asList(directory.listFiles((dir, name) -> name.matches("yourfilePrefix".*?")))
                .stream()
                .forEach(singleFile -> singleFile.renameTo(new File("someNewFilePath")));               
        return RepeatStatus.FINISHED;

    }

}
```

Comment: I second this answer. This is how I would do it too.

Comment: @MahmoudBenHassine your thoughts on moving the file in the after step of the final writer class?

Comment: @Q-RIUS both are valid, but I would use a cleanup step. The reason is that I always create a diagram for the steps of my job, and seeing a cleanup step in the diagram is easier than representing a job listener.